# Selenium click button while accounting for header name

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am new to selenium and would like to download a specific file from a website.
There are multiple class tags whereas each has the heading in the form "[Year] Annual Report". The following is for the year 2017. How can I click the "Download" Button while ensuring that this is the button for a specific year (e.g., 2017 and not 2015)?

```
<li class="" style="display: flex;">
                                <img src="/HostedData/_ara_prvw/68711.jpg" alt="1-800-FLOWERS.COM" title="1-800-FLOWERS.COM" width="182" height="235">
                                <div class="text_block">
                                    <span class="heading">2017 Annual Report</span>
                                    <span class="btn_archived view_annual_report">
                                        <a href="/HostedData/AnnualReportArchive/1/NASDAQ_FLWS_2017.pdf" title="View 2017 Annual Report (PDF)" target="_blank">View Annual Report</a>
                                    </span>
                                    
                                    <span class="btn_archived download">
                                        <a href="/HostedData/AnnualReportArchive/1/NASDAQ_FLWS_2017.pdf" download="">Download</a>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </li>
```

Comment: could you please provide the URL that you are working with?

Comment: Sure. Here is a sample URL: https://www.annualreports.com/Company/1-800-flowerscom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a page you shared you can use the following XPath: `//span[@class='btn_archived download'][.//a[contains(@href,'2017')]]`
So, the Selenium python command to click it can be as following:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[@class='btn_archived download'][.//a[contains(@href,'2017')]]"))).click()
```

Actual code may contain scrolling and more required actions. According to actual code flow.

Comment: Is there an equivalent solution in cases where I would like to search a link text rather than a link itself? E.g., in the following case I would like to search for the links text, so "111, Inc" and not the link itself <a href="/Company/abc-inc">111, Inc.</a>

Comment: sure. instead of `[.//a[contains(@href,'2017')]]` you will use `[contains(.,'111')]` but to give a clear answer I need to see that actual page HTML

Comment: I'm happy I could help again :)